# How to use custom tooltip for dojo-clusteredColumns chart, as we do in dojo-pie charts?

Tags: dojox.charting

I am using dojo toolkit for generating charts.
I have used dojo pie charts, where i gave custom tooltip as

```
  chart1.addSeries("Series 1", [{x:1,y:4,tooltip:"Value is 1"},
                                {x:2,y:6,tooltip:"Value is 2"}]);
```

Similarly, i want to use this feature in ClusteredBars/ClusteredColumns also.
Please, Can anyone kindly suggest me how to give custom-tooltip in ClusteredBars/ClusteredColumns type charts in dojo?

Thanks in advance,
SuryaPavan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
chart1.addSeries("yourSerie", [ {
            y : $m0,
            tooltip : "the text to the serie"
        } ]);
```

Comment: Ya Wire, its solved..
Many thanks!!
hmm.. its such a simple thing :)